# How to get the contents of an elemnt including the listeners

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

My current code is this

```
var existing = element.children().clone(true);
element.empty();
// Do some stuff with element
/* ... */
// Restore the previous content.
element.empty().append(existing);
```

This works well as long as element doesn't contains text directly under it. I mean that it is like that:

```
// Works great, because .children() will get tag2 and tag3, etc.
<element><tag2>...</tag2><tag3>...</tag3></element>

// Doesn't work, because .children() doesn't get the text node.
<element>some_text<tag2>...</tag2></element>
```

So I tried with `.contents()`, however I have some events attached to my initial element (that's why i used `.clone(true)` in the current code) and `.contents()` doesn't get the element with their event.

Do you know any other methode that I could use ? Or can you help me to write some code that will do what I want without being too complicated ?

Thanks a lot.

**EDIT**

I created a this: http://jsfiddle.net/Jv6rW/ to show you. I want that when you click on 'click' it should show the alert message.

Comment: I would delegate the events instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use *.on()* method to bind events. Then you can achieve what you want to do like this way

```
 var existing = element.html();
 element.empty();
  // Do some stuff with element
 /* ... */
 // Restore the previous content.
 element.append(existing);
```

Comment: I created a fiddle: jsfiddle.net/Jv6rW with `.on` and it doesn't work as I want

Answer (score 2):

Rather than trying to clone event listeners, why not use on() event delegation to do that for you?

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Jv6rW/ with `.on` and it doesn't work as I want